# Walk cycle animation not working in blender game engine

Tags: animation, game-engine

I am a bit of a noob when it comes to blender but I'm trying to make a stealth game. So far I have made a mesh character and parented him to an armature. I also made a walk animation that works perfectly in the animation tab. However, when I try to play the animation in the BGE using the logic nodes by pressing "W" my character moves forward just like how I wanted it to, but it does not play the walk animation.
I've made two walk animations named *Walk* and *Walking.001*. they're exactly the same but "Walk" prevents my character from moving and always returns the character to a specific position. I looked at many tutorials to fix this but no progress has been made.
[Here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/31530) is the link to my game.
If anyone can please tell me what to do so I don't come into this problem again, it would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the *Mirror Modifier* and modifier order, to fix it apply the mirror and
change the order so that it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I was not aware that modifiers were available in the Game Engine?